# How I can retrieve the latest records without using lateral join?

Tags: postgresql, join

I have the following database:

```
create table "client" (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR NOT NULL
);

create table store (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL
);

create table "appointments"(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    client_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    appointment_timestamp TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    store_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_user FOREIGN KEY(client_id) REFERENCES "client"(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_store FOREIGN KEY(store_id) REFERENCES "store"(id)
);
```

And I want to retrieve the latest appointments of each user. So far I did is:

```
select 
 * 
from 
 "client"
 left join lateral (
   select 
       * 
   from 
      appointments join store on  appointments.store_id = store.id
   where appointments.client_id = client.id 
  order by appointment_timestamp DESC
  limit 1
 ) as latest_appointment on true
```

But the query may be executed over 7 minutes so I need a way to improve it.
Another approach could be using `where in` but also seems to be a performance killer as well.

Is there a way to retrieve the most recent client appointments and the store that has the latest appointment without using `lateral join` or `where in`?

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: @mustaccio I complied to your suggestions.

Comment: Why "without using lateral join"? Perhaps you want to tune your existing query instead of rewriting it? You should probably show what indexes you have got, along with the output of `explain (analyze, buffers)`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your goal here is to make things faster, which is different than a goal of avoiding the word "LATERAL" just because it is a naughty word.

That kind of lateral join is always executed "in retail", once per each row of the other table.  The planner is not smart enough to convert it to execute in wholesale.  To do that you would want to write it as a DISTINCT ON query.  I believe that the query you show will give the identical answer as the one below, but with a very different plan, but you should study and verify that for yourself:

```
select distinct on (client.id) * from 
client left join (appointments join store on appointments.store_id = store.id) on client.id=appointments.client_id
order by client.id, appointment_timestamp DESC
```

Of course it is possible that the new plan won't actually be faster.  You should look at (and show us) the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for each way.